# Why is OS X giving me a warning about installing apps when I try to open an XML file with Webstorm?

Tags: finder

I've extracted some XML files from an email attachment. I would like to open them in Webstorm instead of Xcode. But when I try to use the "Open With -> Other" and pick Webstorm, I get a message about being unable to install the app. That doesn't make any sense, since xml files are just text. Screenshots:

[image: Open With...]
[image: Warning]

Are XML files somehow defined as apps by OS X? Is there a way to change that? Is this a bug?

I have verified that the file is just xml and it can be opened by WebStorm with no issues. This seems to be a Finder/security issue.

Comment: Which also begs the question: How do you sign an XML so that the OS identifies it as coming from an identified developer? Seems a bit odd. I'll post a workaround though.

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal and type `xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine` followed by a space, then drag the file or folder of files that you can't open directly into the Terminal window, and push return. You should now be able to open the file directly.

Comment: would I have to do that for every file?

Comment: @jcollum if you have a bunch of files in a folder that need this, use the command `xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine`, then a space, but drag the folder in instead, and push return.